# $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$ then $\left\lVert{A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T}\right\rVert_2 = 1$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-rank

I get stuck in the follow problem:

Let $A \in R^{m \times n}$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$ (It's not written but I think $m \geq n$). Show that $\left\lVert{A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T}\right\rVert_2 = 1$ where $B \in R^{m \times n} \Rightarrow \left \lVert {B}\right \rVert_2 = \sup_{||x||=1}\left \lVert {Bx}\right \rVert_2$

**My try:**

I've decided look to $\left \lVert{A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T}\right\rVert_2^2$

And I get the following expression:

$\left \lVert{A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T}\right\rVert_2^2 = \sup_{||x||=1} ({x^TA(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx})$

If we call $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T=B$ then we have

$\left \lVert{A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T}\right\rVert_2^2 = \sup_{||x||=1} <x,Bx>$ ???

And here I get stuck, any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: If $B=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, then what is $B^2$? And what does this imply about the norm?

Comment: $B^2 = B$, can I use $ ||B^2|| = B^2?$

Comment: it does, thank you!